# Improve Pandas Web-scraping Speed

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm currently using pandas pd.read_html() to grab information from Fidelity. It works just fine, but I'm curious if there is a way to improve the speed. Here is my current code below for reference. I've only included a subset of the tickers I'm using.

```
ticker_list = ['FHLC','ONEQ','FTEC']
for i in ticker_list:
    print(i)
    total = 0 
    results = pd.DataFrame()
    while True:
        try:
            url = 'http://research2.fidelity.com/fidelity/screeners/etf/public/etfholdings.asp?symbol={}&view=Holdings&page={}'.format(i,total)
            print(url)
            hd = pd.read_html(url)[0]
            hd['Weight'] = hd['Weight'].apply(lambda x: float(x.split('%')[0])/100)
            print(hd['Weight'].sum())
            results = results.append(hd)
            total += 1 
        except:
            print('Nothing grabbed at page {}'.format(total))
            break
    if results['Weight'].sum() > 0:
        results.to_csv('{}{}.csv'.format(i,todays_date),index=False)
    else:
        print('This fund had no information to add {}'.format(i))
```

Comment: The speed of almost any Web scrapper is determined by the time it actually takes to download the content (in your case, by the time it takes to call `pd.read_html(url)`). There is nothing you can do about it. (Except, perhaps, getting a faster Internet connection?)

Comment: Gotcha. I'm self-taught, but would multi-threading this work? If that makes any sense.

Comment: Multi-threading should help. (But make sure you don't get banned from the source web site for submitting too many requests.)